# VBA Excel Insert a row if condition

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet (doc1) with 4 columns.  In "A" I have people names. In "B","C" and "D", I have informations on the CV of each of these people. I would like to extract in another sheet (doc2) these informations in a specific format: For each CV information, I would like to insert a row with the name of the person in "A" and one information about his CV in "B". **Basically if I have 3 informations about a person in doc1 (In B,C and D), I want to have 3 rows : In A1, A2 and A3 the name of the person, and in B1, B2 and B3 the person's infos.**

I have a macro which does the exact opposite, it is basically doing a Vlookup which throws multiple results. Any idea on how to turn this around? Thanks!

```
Option Explicit

Sub GO()
Dim J As Long
Dim I As Integer
Dim K As Long
Dim Indice As Long
Dim Tablo
Dim Nb As Integer

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  ReDim Tablo(1 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 2, 1 To 2)
  Tablo(1, 1) = Range("A2")
  Tablo(1, 2) = Range("B2")
  Nb = 1
  For J = 3 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For K = 1 To UBound(Tablo)
      If Range("A" & J) = Tablo(K, 1) Then
        For I = 1 To UBound(Tablo, 2)
          If Tablo(K, I) = "" Then
            Tablo(K, I) = Range("B" & J)
            Exit For
          End If
        Next I
        If I > UBound(Tablo, 2) Then
          ReDim Preserve Tablo(1 To UBound(Tablo), 1 To UBound(Tablo, 2) + 1)
          Tablo(K, UBound(Tablo, 2)) = Range("B" & J)
        End If
        Exit For
      ElseIf Tablo(K, 1) = "" Then
        Nb = Nb + 1
        Tablo(K, 1) = Range("A" & J)
        Tablo(K, 2) = Range("B" & J)
        Exit For
      End If
    Next K
  Next J
  With Sheets("doc2")
    .Cells.ClearContents
    .Range("A2").Resize(Nb, UBound(Tablo, 2)) = Tablo
    .Range("A1") = "Name"
    .Range("B1") = "C.V info 1"
    .Range("B1").AutoFill .Range("B1").Resize(, UBound(Tablo, 2) - 1), xlFillSeries
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Excel has built-in functionality that makes VBA not needed. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unpivot-columns-power-query-0f7bad4b-9ea1-49c1-9d95-f588221c7098

Answer (score 0):

try somethihng like this:

```
Function NeverCallAFunctionGO:
   dim doc1 as worksheet, doc2 as worksheet
   dim lRow as long
   'set your doc1 and doc2 sheets

   lRow  = 1
   For i = 1 to doc1.range("A1").end(xldown).row
      doc2.range("A" & lRow).value = doc1.range("A" & i).value
      doc2.range("B" & lRow).value = doc1.range("B" & i).value
      doc2.range("B" & lRow+1).value = doc1.range("C" & i).value
      doc2.rangE("B" & lRow+2).value = doc1.rangE("D" & i).value
      lRow = lRow + 3
   Next i
```